# Tensorflow: train and test in separate functions

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use a Tensorflow model in two separate functions: one that trains it, and one used to test it. For example, the training function looks something like this:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    tf_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, num_dims))
    ...
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_dims, num_labels]))
    ...
    optimizer =    tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)
    prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    ...
    session = tf.Session(graph=graph)
    ...
```

The other, evaluation function would just use `prediction` with the test data, like so:

```
session.run(prediction, feed_dict={tf_dataset: test_data})
```

The problem is, of course, that `tf_dataset` is not in the scope of the other function. I am fine with returning `session` and `prediction` from the training function, but having to share every single placeholder with the evaluation code seems a bit lame.

Is there a way to get the references somehow, from the session or the graph? Also, are there any good practices on how to separate training and evaluation code in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give your placeholders unique names and use that. IE,

```
tf_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, num_dims), name="datainput")
...
sess.run(..., feed_dict={"datainput:0": mydata})
```

You can also get names/type pairs for all ops in your graph, so you could recover all the placeholder tensor names that way

```
[(op.name+":0", op.op_def.name) for op in graph.get_operations()]
```